# JS await for mongoose cursor finish iterating

Tags: mongoose, stream

I'm trying to fetch large data from mongodb

There is my code

```
    let cont = 0
    const stream = await dataModel.find({}).lean().cursor(); // it will return around 2.000 elements
    console.log("Checkpoint one")

    await stream.on('data', async (res) => {
       try {

         cont += 1


       } catch (e) {
         console.log(e)
       }
    });

    await stream.on('close', () => {
      console.log(`Execution ended. Number of elements: ${cont}.`);
    });

    console.log("Checkpoint two")
```

Output:

```
Checkpoint one
Checkpoint two
Execution ended. Number of elements: 2194.
```

Expected output:

```
Checkpoint one
Execution ended. Number of elements: 2194.
Checkpoint two
```

When I'm trying to console log each res inside "on data" function, its also console logging after "Checkpoint two",

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534679/why-even-after-using-async-await-for-multiple-calls-still-got-empty-response

Answer (score 1):

`` javascript
stream.on('close', () => {
      console.log(`Execution ended. Number of elements: ${cont}.`);
    }); ``

This DEFINES (not "executes") a function (that is called each time a stream is closed) and then directly moves on with code-execution. You cannot `await` this, you also cannot `await` the `stream.on('data')` because that's the same issue.
If you want your parent function to wait to a point where the stream has finished reading, you could create a `new Promise` which is fullfilled by your `stream.on('close')` function. You can then `await` that promise just before your `console.log("Checkpoint two")`. This should work, you maybe wanna give it a try.